# Date dimension changes between Test and Production Server

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have a cube deployed into a Test environment and Production environment. I've noticed something strange happen with the date dimension.

When deployed into our test environment, the Date Key comes out looking like this:

[image: Date Key on Test]

However, when deployed into Production it comes out looking like this:

[image: Date Key on Production]

Both servers are running SQL Server 2012 and Analysis Services. On the test environment analysis services is installed on the same machine as SQL Server on the production one it is a different server. Apart from that they should be identical...

I would like the DateKey to look like how it appears in the Test environment. I.e. 2012-12-01 00:00:00.

Comment: Are the Regional Settings of the two servers the same?

Comment: Are you referring to the windows Region and Language settings? then yes, both are set to English (United Kingdom)

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: What language and data format does the OLEDB or ODBC connection from the cube set when connecting to the server? You can see this in sys.dm_exec_sessions from SQL Server (in the language column). Note that this can override regional settings.